# Deserialize an empty list in Web Services

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I'm having trouble with deserializing an empty list from XML.

XML message I'm sending

```
 <dataObj>
    <roleAssignments />
 </dataObj>
```

Java class that I'm deserializing into

```
public class DataObj {
   @XmlElementWrapper(nillable=true)
   private List<RoleAssignmentDataObj> roleAssignments;
}
```

What's happening is that I'm getting back a dataObj with a list of size 1 with a single object with all nulls for values.  If I omit the `<roleAssignments />`, then I get a null in my class.

How can I get a properly empty list in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog posting](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxb-representing-null-and-empty.html) gives examples of how the JAXB XmlElementWrapper is supposed to work.

According to it, what you have written *should* give you an empty collection; see "Mapping #3".

So I think that the real problem is somewhere else.  Maybe the schema does not allow the list to be empty.  Maybe the input XML is not what you think it should be.